# Selecting image in folder using MonoTouch

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm using monotouch and am having a brainfreeze. I'm trying to by code use an image that's in a folder.

The project structure:

Solution
 - Project
   -Images
     -picture.jpeg

The code:

```
UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile("\\Images\\picture.jpeg");
```

And I've also tried:

```
UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile("Images\\picture.jpeg");
```

The build action is set to content and I can use the picture without crashing if I just leave it in the root of the project. What's my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh of course... iOS, paths go by / and not \....

Correct code: `UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile("Images/picture.jpeg");`

Told you it was a brainfreeze!

Comment: For other brainfreezes, don't forget the LoadFromBundle method when you are getting images that are part of your application deployment bundle.